# Laravel 4 :: custom validation error message is not displaying?

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I'm trying to create an online form and to display my own error messages. But for some reason it's not working correctly. Here's my controller code, `CategoryController.php`:

```
class CategoryController extends BaseController
{
    public function add()
    {
        return View::make('admin');
    }

    public function validate_add()
    {
        $rules = array('category_name' => 'Required|Alpha|Min:4');
        $messages = array('category_name.Required' =>'Please enter the category name');
        $input = Input::all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            return Redirect::to('admin')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all()); 
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<h1>WOW! your are are awesome!!! <3<h1> ';
        }
    }
}
```

And the `admin.blade.php`  is following:

```
@extends('common')
@section('body')
<h1>Add Category</h1>
{{ HTML ::ul($errors->all(), array('class'=>'errors')) }}
{{ Form::open(array( 'url'=>'admin', $title="Admin Control Panel")) }}

<p>
    {{ Form::label('Category Name:') }}
    {{ Form::text('category_name', Input::old('category_name'))  }}
</p>
<p>
    {{Form::label('Parent Category') }}
    {{ Form::select('Network', array('0' => 'Maincategory')) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
</p>
{{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

Comment: Are you getting the default error messages back or none at all?

Comment: Could you edit and elaborate "didn't work correctly"? What it does exactly.

Comment: i'm getting default error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting - I tried this on my local Laravel project and it looks like although you can specify your rules in mixed case, you need to specify the custom messages in lower case.

So if you changed your rules and your message override to; 'required' instead of 'Required' etc., it should work.